# Two or more strings within if statement

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I want to know how to use different strings within an if statement

For example:

```
if [ "${variable}" == "String1" ]    
then    
    some command    
fi
```

This works, but when I want to add another string within the if statement I get an error of `too many arguments`.

```
if [ "${variable}" == "String1" "String2" ]    
then    
    some command    
fi
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Your question isn't quite clear.

Comment: if is not a loop! What are you trying to do? Maybe `[ "${variable}" == "String1" -o "${variable}" == "String2" ]`? Or `for variable in String1 String2`?

Comment: Do you want `variable` to be equal to both of the strings individually? Or equal to at least one of the strings? Or equal to both of the string together (concatenated). It isn't clear

Comment: I wanted the variable to be equal to the String1 or String2, I tried using -o between the strings and it worked. Thanks @ExP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to do a comparison with one string *or* another, then you have to do so explicitly. There are two ways of doing this (the first is preferred):

```
if [ "$variable" = "String1" -o "$variable" = "String2" ]; then
    # Do something
fi
```

or

```
if [ "$variable" = "String1" ] || [ "$variable" = "String2" ]; then
    # Do something
fi
```

If you need to compare multiple strings, you might consider a `case` command or, if the strings are sufficiently similar, a *regular expression*.

Comment: The first command worked great for my problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. You can find all of these logical operations (and, or, etc.) in the `bash` manpage by searching for `test expr`. The section is near the bottom (starting line 5114 of 5465 on my laptop).

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this?

```
if [ "${variable}" == "String1String2" ]
```

Comment: I would suggest elaborating.